# How to use gnuplot without X11 forwarding?

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I would like to use gnuplot of a remote pc (under linux) with the help of sftp, but the following error message is thrown:

```
gnuplot: unable to open display ''
gnuplot: X11 aborted.
```

Could anybody help me how to use gnuplot without X11 forwarding?

Comment: Why are you using `sftp`? Why not use ssh and include X forwarding if you are using linux?

Comment: Only reason not to would be lack of access to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and being unable to set `X11Forwarding yes` and restart `ssh`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 8):

You won't be able to display a window, but you can set the terminal to be something else.

```
set term png
set out "test.png"
plot sin(x)
set out
```

That will plot sin(x) to a png file.

Comment: Most likely, `set term eps` and there are a bunch of options. Also just `set term` will show you a list of terminals.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is which I was curious of.